# Random entries Custom Post within last 2 weeks

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get random entries from custom type and custom taxonomy within the last 2 weeks...
The problem is it always show the same 3 entries. I have around 10 entries in total, so I'd like it to show random ones from those 10 every time page refreshes or a person goes to another page.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'country',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => '3', 
    'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '2 weeks ago' ) ),     
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country_categories',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => '25'
        )
    )        
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

        echo '<p><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></p>';

    endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**
To display 10 entries, you have to change your `post_per_page` value to 10.

**Second**
Try [this solution](https://sridharkatakam.com/displaying-entries-on-a-cpt-archive-page-in-random-order-in-wordpress/) to make a random order each time you visit your Archive page:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sk_country_archive_random' );
/**
 * Set Random order for entries in Country archive page
 *
 * @author Bill Erickson
 * @author Sridhar Katakam
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/customize-the-wordpress-query/
 * @param object $query data
 *
 */
function sk_country_archive_random( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'country' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a total of 10 posts in that category, I only want to show 3. But on every refresh I want it to choose 3 different ones out of those 10. I did what you suggested, but still showing the same 3 :(

Comment: @devofash Have you tried logged out? If you see the funciton is telling `!is_admin()`

Comment: Thanks. Yes I logged out. Even tried another browser. I'm trying to show them on the bottom of the full article page...

Comment: @devofash What method are you using to get those posts?